# Use table_2 to show details of each row in table_1 in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have two tables

```
    +----------------+                +---------------+
    |   Fruit_list   |                | Price_history |
    +----------------+                +---------------+
    |   fruit_id     | ----\          |  price_id     |
    |   fruit_name   |      \-------> |  fruit_id     |
    |   *others      |                |  date         |
    +----------------+                |  price        |

    +-------------+---------------+
    |  fruit_id   |  fruit_name   |
    +-------------+---------------+
    |      1      |     Apple     |
    |      2      |     Guava     |
    |      3      |     Starapple |
    |      4      |     Pear      |
    |      5      |     Banana    |
    +-------------+---------------+

    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------+
    |  price_id   |  fruit_id     |   date   |   price  |
    +-------------+---------------+----------+----------+
    |      1      |     2         |  1/25/08 |    1.2   |
    |      2      |     3         |  2/25/09 |    1.8   |
    |      3      |     4         |  9/17/09 |    2.1   |
    |      4      |     2         | 10/16/09 |    0.9   |
    |      5      |     4         |  1/03/10 |    2.5   |
    |      6      |     4         |  1/05/10 |    2.3   |
```

**My question is**
how can i connect these two tables in crystal report in details section using foreign keys or links.

which the report should end up like this

```
    +-------------+-----------+----------+
    |  fruit_name |  date     |   price  |
    +-------------+-----------+----------+
    |   Apple     |    N/A    |    N/A   |
    +------------------------------------+
    |   Guava     |   1/25/08 |    1.2   |
    |             |  10/16/09 |    0.9   |
    +------------------------------------+
    |   Starapple |   2/25/09 |    1.8   |
    +------------------------------------+
    |   Pear      |  9/17/09  |    2.1   |
    |             |  1/03/10  |    2.5   |
    |             |  1/05/10  |    2.3   |
    +------------------------------------+
    |   Banana    |   N/A     |    N/A   |
```

i dont want to use subreports
Please help

I hope this will be clearer now

Comment: Create a VIEW and use this VIEW in crystal reports (_BTW, your question and the sample table output is not clear for me_)

Comment: what is the problem here? what have you tried till now? requirement is simple show your efforts.

Comment: ok..i have tried to split two detail section, `details a` for `fruit_list` table and `details b` for `price_history` table, but the result was  duplicate rows for `fruit_list` and rows without a matching foreign key to `price_history` doesn't show

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this type of requirement.. you need to link tables in database expert and then group by `fruit name` and then place required fields in details section

Comment: Thanks! it worked as what i should expect!. What if there is another table connected to `fruit_name`?for example, i add `buyer_history` table which records whoever buy the fruit?

Comment: You add N number of tables process is same